# How to add Windows 10 from another NVME drive to systemd-boot loader entries?

Tags: windows, dual-boot, boot-loader, systemd-boot

I have tried updating the systemd-boot configuration according to this: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd-boot

I am trying  to add Windows 10 to my boot menu. Here are my drives:

```sh
    kaisellgren@pop-os:~$ lsblk
    NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
    sda           8:0    0 931,5G  0 disk
    ├─sda1        8:1    0   128M  0 part
    └─sda2        8:2    0 931,4G  0 part
    sdb           8:16   0 931,5G  0 disk
    ├─sdb1        8:17   0    16M  0 part
    ├─sdb2        8:18   0   600M  0 part /boot/efi
    └─sdb3        8:19   0 930,9G  0 part /
    nvme0n1     259:0    0 465,8G  0 disk
    ├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   499M  0 part
    ├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0    99M  0 part
    ├─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0    16M  0 part
    └─nvme0n1p4 259:4    0 465,2G  0 part
```

As you can see, my boot SATA3 drive is sdb (partition sdb2).

I have the `/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi` boot loader in nvme0n1 drive in partition 2 (I checked).

So I created this:

```
kaisellgren@pop-os:~$ sudo cat /boot/efi/loader/entries/windows.conf
title Windows
efi /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
options root=UUID=4C58-E6DF
```

And I got the root drive UUID from here:

```
kaisellgren@pop-os:~$ ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jul 10 18:53 02165C56165C4D33 -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Jul 10 18:53 160469B004699391 -> ../../nvme0n1p4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Jul 10 18:53 3C025449025409F2 -> ../../nvme0n1p1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Jul 10 18:53 4C58-E6DF -> ../../nvme0n1p2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jul 10 18:53 5B44-2C7F -> ../../sdb2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jul 10 18:53 646d95a4-1bb4-45c0-96bc-3ee20c4b4211 -> ../../sdb3
```

Here is my loader conf:

```
kaisellgren@pop-os:~$ sudo cat /boot/efi/loader/loader.conf
default Pop_OS-current
timeout 5
```

When I boot my PC, I see the boot menu with two options: PopOS current and old. I see no Windows entry on the list. What am I doing wrong? If I change the timeout parameter, it impacts the boot menu so I am definitely editing the correct configuration files.

Thanks for all the help in advance!

Answer (score 4):

After a long time, I have a found a solution to this, boot into your Linux partition, mount your windows EFI partition in a folder, copy the Microsoft folder to `/boot/EFI/` (on your linux machine), this will do the trick.

The process described in the question of  manually adding a windows.conf to the loader-entries was not necessary for me.

This is the initially mentioned copy-process in detail:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

Look for a partition with the size `100M` and type `EFI System`. You can tell it is the correct one if it's on the same disk with another partition with the size `499M` and type `Windows recovery environment`. Note the device-name of the EFI-partition, e.g. `/dev/nvme0n1p2` (use it with the mount command further down).

Create a directory and mount the Windows-EFI partition into it:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/winefi
sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p2 /mnt/winefi
```

Copy the boot-configuration-data (BCD) to the systemd-boot EFI menu and un-mount the windows-partition:

```
sudo cp -R /mnt/winefi/EFI/Microsoft/ /boot/EFI/Microsoft
sudo umount /mnt/winefi
sudo rm -rf /mnt/winefi
```

This all only works if the GPT/MBR/UEFI/BIOS constellation for Arch is the same as for Windows, e.g. `Arch = GPT/UEFI` can't chain-load `Windows=Bios/MBR` with systemd-boot. See the [wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Dual_boot_with_Windows#Bootloader_UEFI_vs_BIOS_limitations).